# Wait unitl ajax and its callback function finish

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am building a web app that allows users to perform a number of actions simultaneously. For example, user can open a list, delete a list, or add a new list.

Each action makes an ajax call and executes a callback function to update UI upon success. I want to make sure these actions are performed in a serialized manner, so that the UI does not go out of sync. For example, if user opens a list, but deletes the list a fraction of a second later, depending on which ajax call finsihes first, it may display the list which is supposed to be now deleted.

To accomplish this, for each action, I want to wait until an ajax call *and* its callback function are finished. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about disabling UI elements whenever a callback function is initiated, and re-enabling them whenever a callback finishes? As N1ck pointed out below, the `.always` handler would be the place to re-enable your UI elements.

Comment: But if I have multiple simultaneous ajax calls that wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah so you want sequence control. Can I put forth an alternative and suggest you *don't* do this? There's just so many ways such a system could come unstuck. What if a user starts operation A and B within a split second, but A results in error? What if the server receives the request for B before A? Why not build a more robust client-state? Take your example, when the user clicks "Delete", have the client-state immediately delete the item. If the client then receives a command to "View" the item, it refuses.

Comment: Yes, I want to a sequence control. I see. But what if user deletes an item, but the request fails on the server side (due to some constraint violation, for example)? Then, the list is removed on the client side even though it really wasn't.

Comment: In that instance the client-side response to the delete callback could be an error handler which un-deletes the item. Assuming it's the kind of delete operation that doesn't typically fail, this can make your application look *really* fast, because the item is immediately deleted from the users view.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't think about undeleting it on the client side... My delete operation is very unlikely to fail unless the list does not exist already somehow. I'll give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery, you could add `async: false` to your Ajax call or use [Jquery deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to make sure an action is only issued after the Ajax calls are finished (assuming you use Jquery).

If you have multiple Ajax requests, an example could look like:

```
$.ajax({url: url}).pipe(function() {
  // some ajax stuff
  return $.ajax({});
}).pipe(function() {
  // some more ajax stuff (3rd request)
  return $.ajax({});
}).done(function() {
  // done with all ajax requests...
});
```

Comment: True. Error handling isn't considered in this response (and question).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery the `.always()` callback is called after `.done()`/`.fail()`.

```
$.ajax("example.php")
    .done(function() {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        alert("complete"); //Called after done/fail callbacks
    });
```

Comment: This is probably not what I want. I know I can use `.always()`, but I still don't know when the ajax call finishes. For each action, I need to 1) execute the ajax call, and 2) execute the callback. Then, I will move onto processing the next action.

Comment: Your initial callback is `done()` or `fail()`, which is when the ajax call finishes, then `.always()` is called after these callbacks. You could have a boolean to say whether or not it is currently doing an ajax call, and prevent another action being taken, but that seems to defeat the purpose of using ajax at all.

Comment: If I have multiple ajax calls at the same time, I cannot just use a boolean value because one call might set it to false while other ajax calls are in progress. I could use `$.ajaxStart` or `$.ajaxStop()`, but then I wouldn't know when callbacks finish. I guess it does defeat the purpose of ajax calls, but I'm trying to make UI updates in sync. Any suggestions?

Comment: ".. depending on which ajax call finsihes first, it may display the list which is supposed to be now deleted." I think you just need to rethink how you get the updated list after doing an ajax call, what if they delete something from a different browser/tab? If the suggestion above doesn't answer the question, I think you're looking in the wrong area to solve this problem.